# Translating Conv1D Layer from pytorch to tensorflow/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I want to create an equal keras layer from this source:

```
Layer=torch.nn.Conv1d(in_features, out_features, 1)
```

My Input is shaped (Batch_size,Channel,Width)
This Layer is compiled to:

```
Conv1d(10, 256, kernel_size=(1,), stride=(1,))
```

By pytorch.
How can I express this Layer in tensorflow?
I have so far this:

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(in_features-out_features+1, kernel_size=1)
```

But I am not confident that this will is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow's keras you write something like:

```
layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=1)(layer0)
```

Comment: so the filter argument is just the out_features?

Comment: Yes, is the number of filters in layer1(channel number)